# Bootstrapping the view

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I have an issue with bootstrapping the view in my application.

I am trying to get the view instance within the bootstrap so that I can assign view variables etc.

Problem is that I can't seem to do it the recommended way. I can do this:

```
$this->bootstrap('layout');
$layout = $this->getResource('layout');
$view = $layout->getView();
```

and that works fine. get_class($view) returns Zend_View.

But if I do:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
```

I get a blank screen and if I do get_class($view). It returns null.

I have added resources.view[] = to my application.ini.

Any thoughts on why this will not work? I have successfully used the second bit of code on other projects in the past but cannot see any reason why it won't work on this project.

Comment: Why you need to do this? You can set the vars in your controller.

Comment: what is the name of your method in your bootstrap?

Comment: it was _initView. I have now changed it and it works. _initView must be used by the framework. Thanx for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this into Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initViewAdditionalParameters()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
}
```

Comment: Why are you prefixing the method with an underscore? This was a php 4.x throwback to indicate scope before there were scope resolution keywords like protected, public, and private.

Comment: Why all the methods that must be executed by the Bootstrap must start with `_init*`

Comment: I have solved it now. Turns out it was just the method name. It was called _initView, I changed it to _initViewStuff and now it works so I assume _initView is used somewhere else in the bootstrapping process.

Comment: correct! _initView is an internal method probably what you had problems! Set a vote please ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$view = $this->getPluginResource('view')->getView();
```